# How to add new class to only one element in map using scroll event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, scroll

I'm trying to add a new class to li when window.scrollY is in the right value. So far I managed to do it but I've got a problem that when I'm adding a new class to li in the map all of them are getting it. I'm wondering how could I add a new class to only one element.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      newStyle: false,
    };
    this.handleStyleChange = this.handleStyleChange.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleStyleChange, true);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleStyleChange, true);
  }


  handleStyleChange() {
    if (window.scrollY > 970 && window.scrollY < 1660) {
      return this.setState({ newStyle: true })
    }
    return this.setState({ newStyle: false });
  }


  render() {
    const { newStyle } = this.state

    return (
          <div className={active ? 'links active' : 'links'}>
            {links.map((link, i) =>
              <li
                className={newStyle ? 'scrolled-li' : ''}
                key={link.id}>
                <a href={link.href}>{link.name}</a>
              </li>)}
          </div>
    )
  }
```

I expect to add .scrolled-li only to first li when handleStyleChange() will be truthy

Comment: Add a conditional to your style: ``i === 0``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question comes in my mind why you want to do it? is it correct way do it?
You can do this by checking index is 0 or not.

```
{links.map((link, i) =>
              <li
                className={newStyle && i === 0 ? 'scrolled-li' : ''}
                key={link.id}>
                <a href={link.href}>{link.name}</a>
              </li>)}
```

Comment: To highlight an element in navbar when you reach a given section on the page. So if you are between window.scrollY > 970 && window.scrollY < 1660 About on navbar will be highlighted

Comment: So First li is navbar?

Comment: Nope :P li is just link in navbar, and on given height it should change style.
https://vimeo.com/346357750
Look at navbar About

Comment: The approach is correct, but you may need to highlight other nav bar on different hight. You can add some hight calculate logic and some state management for all links. You can check out this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36121450/highlighting-current-section-in-navbar

Comment: If you want to highlight the first link only this will work like charm.

Comment: Awesome! Thank's for help :) I'll look at it right away ^^ Actually i do want to  highlight other elements too! So thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to achieve this:

1) This will add the class only to first element.

```
{links.map((link, i) =>
  <li
    className={newStyle && !i ? 'scrolled-li' : ''}
    key={link.id}>
    <a href={link.href}>{link.name}</a>
  </li>)}
```

2)
Use [first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) css selector at the parent element.